# Show month name instead of month number (fetched from db) in django model choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

Column *acct_per_num* in table *SAPAdjustment* contains the month number. The following code gives a dropdown with unique month numbers (1,2,3) present in column *acct_per_num* in table *SAPAdjustment* but I want month names (January, February, March) instead of month numbers (1,2,3).

forms.py

```
class SAPReconForm(forms.Form):
    month = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SAPAdjustment.objects.values_list('acct_per_num',flat=True).distinct(), empty_label=None)
```

models.py

```
class SAPAdjustment(models.Model):
    acct_per_num =  models.IntegerField( blank=True,null=True, verbose_name =_('Month'),help_text=_('Month'))
```

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.6.7 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`calendar`** module as,

```
import calendar

values = SAPAdjustment.objects.filter(acct_per_num__range=[1, 12]
                                      ).values_list('acct_per_num', flat=True
                                                    ).distinct().order_by('acct_per_num'
                                                                          )
month_choices = [(value, calendar.month_name[value]) for value in values]

from django import forms


class SAPReconForm(forms.Form):
    month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=month_choices)
```

Also, Use **`ChoiceField(...)`** instead of **`ModelChoiceField`**